# 13.5 Hp Briggs & Stratton engine not wanting to turn over after head gasket replacement

Tags: head-gasket

After replacing the head gasket on my Briggs and Stratton 13.5 Hp engine acts as if it does not want to turn over but upon removing the spark plug engine turns over find a tax as if it's get building up too much compression note I never loosen the rocker arms up they are at the same adjustment they were before the head gasket replacement. can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

If it is an overhead valve engine the valves Must be re-adjusted after head gasket removal and replacement (any time the head is removed), this is most likey the issue. My Briggs V twin had the same hard crank or crank and stop issue but due to many hours of run time, adjusted the valves and Wha-La, turned over like a champ.

This is a known issue with Briggs overhead valve engines, valve adjustment must be on spec for easy cranking.

Comment: Does B&S have the pressure relief thing? Where, during cranking, this is there to allow the motor to spin, then once started it doesn't do it anymore ... wish I remembered what it was called ...

Comment: Not any that I have ever seen. I mostly see those on old high compression 2 strokes 250cc and up

Comment: Known as a decompression lever - used it on some single cylinder diesels such as Petter, set the decompression lever (which holds the exhaust valve open), swing the engine over until you have sufficient speed and knock the lever off. If you are lucky it continues to run. Better than a gym workout when it does not start though...

Comment: @SolarMike - It appears it's also called a "compression release" ... and I believe that's what Moab is getting at with adjusting the valves.